# How to make csv file disabled with R1C1 in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

I am using a pandas script to read some values from a .csv file, However, the file I have always enabled with R1C1 under formulas, how to disable this permanently using python

Comment: what means `R1C1 under formulas` ? Show example data and expected result.

Comment: R1C1- Relative notation. this term is related to Excel.

Comment: `csv` is text file and you can open it even in text editor. If you have something strange which is related to Excel then problem is not csv file but rather in Excel export. Now you can only edit `csv` in editor or edit it after loading to pandas.